# how to make Default Network detection working after reboot

Tags: java, android

Go directly to **EDIT** part.

My app have to detect default network changes and make a HTTP request then (if connected, of course).
All works well, but, when the phone reboots, network change isn't detected anymore.

I added BroadcastReceiver which is launched at reboot, but I don't understand what I have to do with. Have I to create registerDefaultNetworkCallback again?
Have I to outsource the detection part to use it from MainActivity AND from BraodcastReceiver? If yes, how can I do that please?

My sample code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {
                // my HTTP request in background, works fine
                // parameter needed : Activity (MainActivity.this here)
                // for background task
            }
        });
    }
}

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // what should I do here?
        // how to access to Activity, needed for BackgroundTask
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that the BroadcastReceiver is mandatory to detect the reboot and restart the network change detection. And my problem is that I don't know how to do a BackgroundTask with it since I don't have an Activity. But if I'm completely wrong and my app's network change detection can very well continue on reboot in another way, that's obviously ideal.

**EDIT:**

I'm going to ask my question differently, so as not to influence the answers with my way of doing things:

For my personnal use only, I want to create an app that do a HTTP request each time my IP change (default network change is sufficient) EVEN after reboot.
The user (me) starts the app ONCE only and doesn't need to restart it (in any way), even after reboot, and the IP change detection continues to work ALWAYS.

It that possible one way or another? And if yes, how please?

Answer (score 0):

You cant start an activity from background, but you dont need activity for your connectivity monitor. Depending on what you do in its callback, you can either start a foreground service to show some info in notifications - and make notification open activity if clicked (thats polite to user), or maybe allow work in background (thats less polite) - but you will risk android killing your app - foreground service will allow to keep your app alive.

Also your user will have to manually start your app at least once to make ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED work.

To make it even harder, various manufacturers optimize their devices, preventing such background app like yours from eating resources. You must be prepared for that. See this page: https://dontkillmyapp.com/. I remember having lots of problems on xiaomi, I needed to show user information dialog with information on how to make changes in the device UI to allow for device to work in background in she/he want to.

Comment: Of course my app is manually started by the user.
I can't believe there isn't a solution to my problem, given how many apps seem to me to act the way I want. I think I'm not architecting my application correctly and posing the problem correctly. I'm going to edit my question to make my question more specific but less dependent on how I do things.